# Using $this when not in object context Cant seem to fix it

Tags: php

I keep getting this error, and I checked everything but I cant find the solution.

```
    public function logout($redirect = '') {
    $logout = $this->_db->delete('user_sessions', array('id', '=', $this->data()->id));
    Session::delete($this->_sessionName);
    Cookie:delete($this->_cookieName);
    Session::flash("home","Succesvol uitgelogd.");
    (isset($redirect) && isset($logout)) ? Redirect::to($redirect) :     Session::flash("home","Uitloggen mislukt."); Redirect::to("home");        
}
```

The problem seems to happen here:

```
$logout = $this->_db->delete('user_sessions', array('id', '=', $this->data()->id));
```

The problem lies in the syntax here, it cant be anything else I think.

### The code

#### User.class.php

Full class: http://pastebin.com/v0GTnZUs

```
public function checkUserAgent() {               
        $_new_agent = ($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] != $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ? false : $_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);        
        $_cur_agent = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

        $_msg = 'Er is een fout opgetreden betreft uw login, graag opnieuw inloggen zodat we weten wie u bent.<br />Sorrie voor het ongemak.';

        return ($_cur_agent !== $_new_agent) ? User::logout() && Session::flash('msg_login',$_msg) && URL::redirect("members/login") : true;              
    }
```

Here's the code where logout() is called.

But this problem is occuring alot of times so I hope I can get to understand this error, saves me alot of time.

#### DB.class.php

Full class: http://pastebin.com/wySUDF5T

PS: The problem isnt where logout() is called and of that part is in or out the object scope. I got two pieces were I use $this first part is "$this->_db->delete" second part is "$this->data()->id" and these two parts are on the line of the error but I am guessing the second cause I am using alot of times "$this->_db->get" and I am only getting a problem when I used the code at the top of this post the checkUserAgent()

Comment: Well, that function is _not_ implemented in the class you cite. So where _is_ its implementation? What class _is_ it part of? How do you expect us to help if you do not post all relevant code? Obviously the function is called outside an object content (the error is definite). That has nothing to do with the db class. It is the function `logout()` that is called outside an object scope, so where no `$this` exists.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the implementation you posted for [`User.class.php`](http://pastebin.com/v0GTnZUs) this method is defined as static.

```
public static function logout($redirect = NULL) {
    ...
}
```

In static methods you are in a **class context**, not in an **instance context**, so there is no `$this`.

Comment: That was only there for seconds, I just put it there to see it if changes things.

But this is good to know tho

Comment: So what is the latest version now? How are we supposed to help you if we do not now the code base?